# jQuery change <select> drop down to fancy html

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a `<form>` and I want to replace the classic `<select>` with a fancy HTML list `<ul>` so I can style it better with CSS, and in the same time maintain the `<form>` to function properly when an option `<li>` is selected.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

May be [***`chosen`***](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is the library which you want to use:

```
$("select").chosen(); // just do this to use chosen.
```